# SSHFS mounting remote ssh server causes Segmentation fault: 11 on mac OS

Tags: macos, fuse, sshfs

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tzhenghao/writing-remote-code-on-a-mac-with-sshfs-c62d64bf9ef9) mounting a SSH server on macOS. I installed with

```
brew install cask osxfuse
```

and SSHFS with

```
brew install sshfs
```

but when I try to mount the remote folder to a local folder with

```
sshfs foo@bar:/remote/folder ~/local/folder
```

I get the error:

> Segmentation fault: 11

My OS is

> **macOS High Siera 10.13.6 (17G65)**

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this and the cause on my end was a missing space between the colon and the start of the directory.

```
sshfs foo@bar: /remote/folder ~/local/folder
```

Comment: opposite worked for me. Also it seemed that user@server: without a directory immediately appended caused the segfault, but user@server:/home/user worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know what the problem was but from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/6m2jhj/tutorial_filesystem_over_ssh_sshfs/) I tried

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions foo@bar:/remote/folder ~/local/folder -p 22
```

then the `folder` disappeared and a new drive called OSXFUSE Volume 0 (sshfs) showed up:

[image]

although it is still pretty unstable and gets disconnected frequently.